# PHP advanced strtotime convert

Tags: php, date

I have date and times like:

```
12-Oct-13 09:15 PM AEST
10-Oct-13 07:05 PM AEST
```

I used strtotime() function of PHP Like this to convert this to a datetime object as below:

```
echo $datetime=strtotime('12-Oct-13 09:15 PM AEST');
```

But it getting empty results. My idea is convert the above datetime to another format like:

```
12-10-2013 09:15 PM
10-10-2013 07:05 PM
```

Can anyone help me with that to properly convert to a datetime object. Then I use that in my code.

Comment: The problem lies in the "AEST" part, when you remove that from the date, strtotime() works like u expect it to.

Comment: Have you considered using datetime create from format ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: DateTime is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP doesn't support `AEST` timezone, that's why `strtotime()` returns `false`. See [list of supported TZ's](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

You can still convert your input to needed output:

```
$input = '12-Oct-13 09:15 PM AEST';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y H:i A *', $input);
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y h:i A'); # 12-10-2013 09:15 PM
```

or, since `AEST` timezone is `+10:00` offset from `UTC`, just string replace it:

```
$input = '12-Oct-13 09:15 PM AEST';
$input = str_replace(' AEST', ' +1000', $input);
$dt = new DateTime($input);
print_r($dt);
/*
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2013-10-12 21:15:00
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +10:00
)
*/
```

or, cut timezone part from a string:

```
$input = '12-Oct-13 09:15 PM AEST';
$input = substr($input, 0, strrpos($input, ' '));

echo date_create($input)->format('d-m-Y h:i A'); # 12-10-2013 09:15 PM
# or
echo date('d-m-Y h:i A', strtotime($input)); # 12-10-2013 09:15 PM
```

Comment: Clever use of `*`. +1

Comment: @AmalMurali: tnx for fixing typos ;)

Comment: thanks i used strtotime(str_replace(' AEST','',$date))  this returns the thing what i want

Comment: @smithbandara: like I said, cut timezone from string is also a option. If you only have `AEST` timezone, then your code will work, but if you have other, unsupported timezone, then you will have same problems that you stated in the question.

Comment: yes my script only using Australian Eastern Standard Time values.so np with that.